# How to animate objects with bobbing up and down motion in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

I have created a 2D platform game with Unity and C# where I have collectable items that can be picked up by the player. What I want is to give the items more focus by having them bobbing up and down.

I came up with the following version:

```
Vector2 floatY;

public float FloatStrength; // Set strength in Unity

void Update () {
    floatY = transform.position;
    floatY.y = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time) * FloatStrength);
    transform.position = floatY;
}
```

But, this makes the object float in the middle of the level instead of where the object is positioned. How can I fix that?

Here is a screenshot of the prototype of the game:

[image]

The player can collect the wood stumps which should be bobbing up and down in space just above the ground.

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you've tried? That'll give people a starting point and makes it more likely for you to get an answer that you can use. It's likely you're looking for simple harmonic motion.

Comment: use a sine wave to determine the amount to move and the direction per frame and adjust the y pos on your floating object ... assuming y is up and down. This question is so vague that's about the best I can suggest without clarity.

Comment: @Wardy, I have update my code and I think this is what you suggest. Is that right?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Do you mean if it is 2D or 3D? It's a 2D plaformer.

Comment: I have update the question.

Comment: Have you been able to have a non-float collectible first? Your issue seems to be about positioning that item, not about making it float. Unfortunately, this is really to broad and/or we're lacking the information to help you...

Comment: Yes I am been able to have non-floatable items.

Comment: By all means, show us!

Comment: Hey Caspert between you and @pip you basically have the bits you need to solve this now, simple enough right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a pretty simple solution. What your problem here is that you are not preserving the original y position. Essentially, you need to store the original y position in a variable, that would look like this: (Don't forget to set the variable in the Start() function.)

```
Vector2 floatY;
float originalY;

public float floatStrength;

void Start ()
{
    this.originalY = this.transform.position.y;
}

void Update () {
    floatY = transform.position;
    floatY.y = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time) * floatStrength);
    transform.position = floatY;
}
```

After that, I suggest that instead of directly setting the y value of the floatY to `Mathf.Sin(Time.time) * floatStrength`, you set it based on the sum of that value and the original transform position. The final code should look something like this:

```
Vector2 floatY;
float originalY;

public float floatStrength;

void Start ()
{
    this.originalY = this.transform.position.y;
}

void Update () {
    floatY = transform.position;
    floatY.y = originalY + (Mathf.Sin(Time.time) * floatStrength);
    transform.position = floatY;
}
```

Finally, instead of storing floatY as a Vector, you could store it as a float. Alternatively, you could use `transform.position` directly, doing something like this:

```
Vector2 floatY;
float originalY;

public float floatStrength;

void Start ()
{
    this.originalY = this.transform.position;
}

void Update () {
    /* Old code:
    floatY = transform.position;
    floatY.y = originalY + (Mathf.Sin(Time.time) * floatStrength);
    transform.position = floatY;
    */
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 
        originalY + (Math.Sinf(Time.time) * floatStrength));
}
```

Finally, the last step is to do some minor refactoring as to remove some errors that have popped up along the way. `Math.Sin` (Note: not `Math.Sinf`) yields a `double` instead of the desired `float`, so we have to explicitly convert that value. Next, we can remove the `Vector2 floatY` completely. Note that this would need to actually be a Vector3 to store `transform.position`, as that also has a `z` component, if we were to actually have kept using that. Finally, we must fix that same problem in the `Update()` function, and change:

```
    transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 
        originalY + (Math.Sinf(Time.time) * floatStrength));
```

to:

```
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
        originalY + (Math.Sinf(Time.time) * floatStrength), transform.position.z);
```

That code segment does not implement the other changes that I mentioned. In the end the complete code is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class FloatBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    float originalY;

    public float floatStrength = 1; // You can change this in the Unity Editor to 
                                    // change the range of y positions that are possible.

    void Start()
    {
        this.originalY = this.transform.position.y;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
            originalY + ((float)Math.Sin(Time.time) * floatStrength),
            transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Note that this code can be attached to an object either through `New Object >> 2D >> Sprite` and then by adding this code as a script, or through the following code programmatically:

```
    GameObject object = new GameObject();
    object.name = "Floating Box";
    object.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = SOME_SPRITE;
    object.AddComponent<FloatBehavior>();
```

Here's an example of what this could look like:

[image: Sample Image illustrating code]

Edit: Fixed compile errors

Comment: Thanks Pip for the answer. Unfortunately, I receive the following error: `The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing!`. The floated object have a `box collider 2D` and a `Rigidbody2D`.

Comment: @Caspert can you include a screenshot of the error, a pastebin of the code, and the line number that that occurred on?

Comment: @Caspert also, I suggest removing the Rigidbody2D while keeping the box collider, as you don't actually need it in this case. If you do not have a SpriteRenderer on the object, I suggest adding one and using the image with that rather than rendering it directly.

Comment: here is the error that I receive after past your code in mine. http://i59.tinypic.com/2aeo41g.jpg

Comment: @Caspert the issue here is a missing semicolon, which I have fixed. Next time, try playing around with the code before you ask a question, and then you can edit the answer as needed.

Comment: You're right! I will do that in future! Unfortunately, I received some new errors: http://i.imgur.com/1mBN8BS.png - Just used the above last piece of code. Or should I use one of the other? @Pip

Comment: @Caspert I just plugged the code into Unity and made a few minor edits. Answer will be updated shortly

Comment: @Caspert have you tried this yourself? I have tested this myself as you can see by the gif above. If this solution works for you, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: Yes absolutely! I have already accept your answer! Thanks for your help and of course the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I use this for my 3D game:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class BobbingEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    float originalY;

    public float floatStrength = 1; // You can change this in the Unity Editor to 
                                    // change the range of y positions that are possible.

    void Start()
    {
        this.originalY = this.transform.position.y;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
            originalY + ((float)Math.Sin(Time.time) * floatStrength),
            transform.position.z);
            transform.Rotate(0,1,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this solution different from the one posted 3 years ago? In fact it looks like a copy&paste from the last code snippet from the old answer, just with a `transform.Rotate(0,1,0);` added to it. Can you tell us what that line does and why it's an improvement?